# How can I cache two $_POST values if they are submitted at different times on the same php page?

Tags: php, http-post

I have a html form which generates a second html form via `$_POST`.

The first form submits `$_POST['id']`, which will then generate another form that will submit $_POST['fields'] which is used to update a `mysql db`. However, the `mysqli query` used to update the `db` relies on both `$_POST['id']` *and* `$_POST['fields']` values.

I can't work around how to submit `$_POST['fields']` without `$_POST['id']` being reset, because `$_POST['fields']` is generated precisely by the submission of `$_POST['id']`.

I tried passing `$_POST` values to `$_SESSION`, and while the values are passed successfully, the `$_POST['id']` value will always reset to NULL once `$_POST['fields']` is submitted. Here's the whole code:

```
<?php 

include 'head.html';
echo "<body>";
include 'connection.php';   

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysqli_error());
$querytwo = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='{$_POST[id]}'") or die(mysqli_error());

//generates $_POST['id'] form

echo "<form action=\"admin.php\" method=\"post\"><select name=\"id\">";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        echo "<option value=\"$row[id]\">$row[firstName] $row[lastName]</option>";
    }
echo "</select><input type=\"submit\"></form><br>";

 //generates $_POST['fields'] form

if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) 
{   
        $rowtwo = mysqli_fetch_array($querytwo);    
        $exclude = array(2);

        for($column_value = 0; $column_value < 17; $column_value++) 
         {
            if (in_array($column_value, $exclude)) 
            {
                continue;
            }
                $field = mysqli_field_name($querytwo, $column_value);
                echo "<form method=\"POST\">" . "$field" . ": <input type=\"text\" name=\"fields\" value=\"$rowtwo[$column_value]\"><input type=\"submit\"></form>";    
        }
}  

 //updates db with $_POST['id'] and $_POST['fields'] values

if (isset($_POST['field']) && !empty($_POST['field']))
{
    $column_value = range(0, 20);
    $field = mysqli_field_name($querytwo, $column_value);
    mysqli_query("UPDATE table SET '$field'='{$_POST[fields]}' where id='{$_POST[id]}'");

} else 
{
 echo "not updated yet";    
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1):

Try session variables. At the top of your PHP file (BEFORE any HTML) put `session_start()`, then set `$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']`, and finally access the stored variable in your mysql call with `$_SESSION['id']`.

Session variables will stay accessible until the user closes their browser window (or after about 20 minutes, when they time out), and are secure because they are stored on the server, not as cookies.

Comment: I tried that doing exactly that, except $_SESSION will be reset to NULL when a $_POST value is submitted after a $_POST has already been submitted.

Comment: Make sure you do `session_start()` both times. Once you start a session, the session should never be NULL unless you close the session, the user closes their browser window, or the timeout of ~20 minutes is reached. If the session is still NULL that means your server is not configured right.

Comment: Previously I tried some debugging, where I would set $_SESSION = "43", or some random number. $_SESSION was working in this instance because I would reset the page and a var_dump would indicate that $_SESSION was still equal to its defined value. However, this $_POST thing is still not working.

Comment: This should not be the case. Can you comment a pastebin of your FULL code with sessions or something to work with?

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the second form, pass `$_POST['id']` to it and put it in a `hidden` input.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know if is the best way to do this, but in this case, i would put an extra hidden input named ID in the second form too. 

Something like :

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$_POST['id']."' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `id` parameter in hidden tag.

```
    for($column_value = 0; $column_value < 17; $column_value++) 
     {
        if (in_array($column_value, $exclude)) 
        {
            continue;
        }
            $field = mysqli_field_name($querytwo, $column_value);
            echo "<form method=\"POST\">" . "$field" . ": <input type=\"text\" name=\"fields\" value=\"$rowtwo[$column_value]\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$_POST['id']\"> <input type=\"submit\"></form>";    
    }
```